# jQueryUI sortable placeholder index incorrect

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a sortable list that has a corresponding data array, I need to change the order of the array when the list is reordered. I use this code

```
o.dom.$editor.find('.sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('startIndex', start_pos); // store original index
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('startIndex'); // get original index
        var index = ui.placeholder.index() - 1; // get new index
        console.log(start_pos, index); // log start and end positions for debugging

        ui.item.data('startIndex', index); // store new index
    }
});
```

As an example, let's say I have this list:

```
A
B
C
```

I hold list item A and drag it down to the bottom, the change event fires twice, first swapping item A with item B, then A with C, the console shows:

```
0 1
1 2
```

And it's correct. Now (WITHOUT releasing the mouse from the previous drag), I drag back item A to the top, again the change event fires twice, swapping A with C, then A with B, console shows:

```
2 1
1 0
```

All good.
Now if I release the mouse, and start dragging item B to the top, the change event fires once, swapping B with A, but console shows:

```
1 -1
```

Which is wrong. What's going on here? I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dtdk2qo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `var index = ui.placeholder.index() - 1;` line.

- When you move item from up to down , index for `ui.placeholder.index()` starts from `1`
- when you move item from down to up , index for `ui.placeholder.index()` starts from  `0`

I have changed logic of getting index.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
   var start_pos = ui.item.index();
   ui.item.data('startIndex', start_pos);
 },
 change: function(event, ui) {
   var start_pos = ui.item.data('startIndex');
   var index = ui.placeholder.index();
   index = (start_pos > index) ? index : index - 1; 
   $("#output").append(start_pos + ' ' + index + '<br>');
      ui.item.data('startIndex', index);
 }
  });
})
```

```css
li{
  display: block;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin:20px 0;
}

#output{
  width:100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul class='sortable'>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

<div id="output">
```

Comment: Why does ui.placeholder.index() start from different indexes depending on if I start moving up or down? Is it intended behavior?

Comment: @d.a.vorm, That thing I have not investigated , I will when I will have time Sorry.